# Can't select Suppression list and targeted list in Email studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, suppressionlist

I have created a salesforce data extension with a list of prospects to send email.
Also created a suppression list. While selecting audience type I can't select both Salesforce data extension and suppression list. I am able to select only one at a time. How can I select both?

Comment: You could write an exclusion script that combines the supression list in the script code and connect it with boolean algebra to the already existing exclusion script. It would look like a rowcount to the supressionlist for that subscriber > 1 OR (exclusionscript)). Result would be what you want

Answer (score 0):

Did you try selecting 'All Audience Types' from the list?

[image]

You can then drag and drop your list/data extension to the corresponding areas: 
[image]

Comment: Hi Rachid ,                                                                                                                              
              I have already selected All audience types. I can drag and drop salesforce data extension  But can't drag and drop suppression lists.